# Processing a file using sql bulk copy

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am processing a file using sql bulk copy. I have to process 2 records together, e.g a record starting with "2E" must be followed by a record starting with "3E". Using bulk copy, it may happen that if I process 10 records, one combination of "2E" and "3E" is not available. Please help

Comment: why do they need to be processed together? if they are being bulk-loaded into a table, they just get dumped in so it doesn't matter when they are processed. Or if there is some specific validation or trigger happening, please add details to the question.

Comment: How exactly do you think we can help you? Send an E3? If you should not process an E2 without an E3, *don't*. If you have problems with a specific problem, feel free to ask a specific question.

Comment: If you need row by row control then sql bulk copy is not he appropriate tool.

Comment: My exact problem is that, a row in the table is saved with a combination of records of "2E" and "3E". A field in my row has to come from "3E" and rest from "2E". Also, the field added by "3E" is nullable.